# Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb gets error Could not load file or assembly System.Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an existing web form website and trying to upgrade authentication from Membership to Identity with Owin.
I tried to install those packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

But after installed the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package, I got error as below:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Query, Version=1.0.2319.19041, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I also tried to remove out this package, It worked again, but would get error if I try to re-install the package.

Have anybody faced with this issue can help me to solve?

Thank you,
Giang.

Comment: How are you installing these packages? using nuget? Have you tried starting on a blank solution with identity enabled? Which are the versions of asp.net and visual studio that you are using?

Comment: Hi Zed, yes I have installed from Nuget. But there is so wired that I did the same for another project and it worked fine. Only one project got the error related to "System.Query". I'm confusing why this package has relationship to "System.Query" and why it only happening on one project.